# Is a Poisson r.v.'s parameter a rate $\mu$ or a count $\mu t$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let's say I want to model the arrivals of some quantity of interest, say customers coming to a store. I know that on average, $\mu$ customers arrive in on hour. My understanding is that if $N$ is the number of customers to arrive in an hour, then

$$
N \sim \text{Pois}(\mu)
$$

Now I think of $\mu$ as a rate, e.g. $\mu$ customers per hour. But I can also reason about the number of customers in $t$ hours, which is

$$
N_t \sim \text{Pois}(\mu t)
$$

My confusion is: in the first example, the dimensions of $\mu$ are

$$
\mu\;\frac{\text{people}}{\text{hours}}
$$

whereas the dimensions of $\mu t$ are

$$
\mu\;\frac{\text{people}}{\text{hours}} \times t\;\text{hours} = \mu t \; \text{people}
$$

What's going on? Is the parameter an average *rate* or an average *count*? Or is the first object a Poisson r.v. while the second object is a Poisson process?

Comment: A Poisson process is specified by the mean rate of arrivals per unit time $\lambda$ so that in a time interval $(0,t]$ there are, on average, $\lambda t$ arrivals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpretation of any given parameter depends on context. But you can resolve your specific question by viewing $\mu$ as "people per hour" in both cases, and viewing $N$ as the special case $t=1$; that is the "$\mu$" in $\text{Pois}(\mu)$ is actually $\text{Pois}(\mu \cdot 1)$.

In general, the parameter of a Poisson *process* is a rate (arrivals per unit of time), and the parameter of a Poisson random variable is a counting unit (number of people, number of arrivals, etc.). In your example $\mu$ is a rate, and $\mu \cdot 1$ is a counting unit.